# Random Trailer app in Django

Tags: django, youtube

I'm very new to Django and am trying to build my first good app. I've decided to try to rebuild a website of low complexity, and chose: http://trailertrack.me/

I was wondering if you could tell me which steps to take.

Right now, my views.py file looks like this (I'm only trying to show one specific video at the moment):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
import gdata.youtube
import gdata.youtube.service

yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
yt_service.ssl = True

def index(request):
    message = "Welcome, and enjoy the show!"
    context = {
            'message': message,
    }
    return render_to_response('index.html', context)

def video(request):
    t = loader.get_template('index.html')
    specificentry = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoEntry(video_id='1g4PLj0PlOM')
    return HttpResponse(t.render(specificentry))
```

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: First off, you don't usually want to be doing `loader.get_template`; use `django.shortcuts.render(request, 'index.html', {'video_entry': specificentry})`. Beyond that, though, it seems like you'll need a way to get a random entry, a "next" button, etc. What specific problems are you having?

Comment: Thanks Dougal. Well, a minor problem is I'm getting this: "No module named gdata.youtube"

Comment: Apart from that, not really sure of how to do the rest. The API docs assume you have experience. What would be your next steps?

Comment: That probably means that the `gdata` package isn't available. Have you installed it (preferably [in a virtualenv](http://www.mahdiyusuf.com/post/5282169518/beginners-guide-easy-install-pip-and-virtualenv-1))?

Comment: I had not done that, thanks. Why virtualenv?

Comment: Virtualenv lets you manage dependencies for separate projects separately, so that if you have more than one Django project, you can e.g. update the version of Django independently from each other or of any other required package. It also makes it a lot easier to track what dependencies your project needs and to install them on a different computer / server.

Comment: Cool. Appreciate the help. Any guidelines for the rest of the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's a broad outline of how I'd go about doing this. The order doesn't matter too much; there's obviously some dependencies among them, but do them in the order that you feel like tackling them.

Also, if you're new to this, I'd strongly recommend using either [git](http://git-scm.com/) or, if you're already familiar with it, [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) for version control, and [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) for tracking dependencies.

1. Get your current views working, so that you can see that one specific video with a reasonable-looking template and so on.
2. Add a way to show more than that one video. One straightforward way to do this is to create a simple Django model for videos, with basically just a youtube ID, and turn on the admin site so you can add videos manually.
3. Make the view show a random video on each load.
4. Add a "next" button that just reloads the page. You can either use a django session variable / GET variable to avoid showing the same video again, or just assume it won't happen often enough to be a problem if you have a lot of videos.
5. Add a way to get new videos from Youtube (semi-)automatically. One way to do this:

   - Add an "is published" field to your video model, and have the user-facing site only show published videos.
   - Make a management command that does a Youtube search for "trailer" or something and adds new videos (unpublished) to the database. (Check for duplicate IDs at the very least.) Run that automatically in cron every few hours or days or whatever.
   - Go into the admin periodically and add new videos. If you want, you can make a custom admin view that shows a bunch of pending videos on a page, with their metadata, the actual video so you can watch it, and any other videos that might be duplicates in the system, along with AJAX publish and delete buttons. (The duplicates thing is a little harder! You can probably just do [tf-idf weighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf-idf) on the metadata to find similar videos.
6. Add a way for users to log in (the default Django users system, Facebook/Twitter integration, whatever) and like/upvote/maybe downvote videos. Remember these. Add video recommendations with some form of [collaborative filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering).
7. You now have more features than the original site! Think of some other cool ones and implement them too. :)